# c++ virtual function and executable

Tags: c++

There are a few questions concerning vptr and exe:

1) When is vTable created and populated ie compile-time or run-time?

2) Does compiler put vptr in exe ie size of exe increases with no. of classes having virtual functions

3) Does executable size grows when we run it and when it contain virtual functions

Comment: Since all the things you talk about are outside the standard, you must be asking about how a specific implementation works. So maybe you tell us what implementation you talk about.

Comment: Unless you are in a very memory constrained environment, you will not notice the sizes of the vtables (just a few pointers shared by all objects of the same type), it will more probably have a higher impact the extra vote in each instance of the type.

Comment: to PlasmaHH:These questions were asked in a telephonic interview and nothing was mentioned about the specific implementation

Comment: to David Rodriguez: These questions were asked in telephonic interview and the stress was on memory and speed optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all implementation defined and will vary from compiler  to compiler, The standard does not mention how dynamic dispatch should be implemented, it does not even use the words vtable and vpointer, but all known compilers implement dynamic dispatch through vtable and assuming that answers to your questions are:

**When is vTable created and populated ie compile-time or run-time?**
Compile time
vtable is created for each class with atleast one virtual method during compilation phase.

**Does compiler put vptr in exe ie size of exe increases with no. of classes having virtual functions?**
Yes, most likely
Since the vtable has to reside somewhere in memory, it will occupy some memory space for sure.

**Does executable size grows when we run it and when it contain virtual functions?**
No there is no runtime growth of exe.
Only the dispatch of functions happens at run-time, the mechanism to make that dispatch happen is constructed at compilation.

Comment: Thanks Als for the helpful comments. For 2nd point: Can vtable reside outside of exe?

Comment: @user1184900: ofcourse, not. An executable of your program can run just by itself(with dynamic library dependencies in place) so the `vtable` must reside in the exe.

Answer (score 2):

This is completey compiler-dependent. The C++ standard has no notion of a vtable.

Answer (score 1):

The actual implementation isn't defined by the standard, but typically,
there will usually be only one vtable per class, with static lifetime.
This will increase the size of the executable, but normally only
marginally—nothing significant.

The vptr is part of the class image: it will increase the size of a
class instance by the size of a pointer (or more, depending on alignment
restrictions and where the compiler puts it in the class).  It will also
cause additional code to be generated for the constructor; again, this
is almost always neglible.  The fact that often a virtual function
cannot be inlined can have a significant impact on performance, and in
some cases, size as well; inlining a simple function can often expose
additional possibilities for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for gcc, the VTable is created at compile-time, although it may be adjusted at runtime if you have `-fPIC`. It costs a few bytes per class, per function: a negligible amount compared to everything else.